# How to inject dependency to waterfallstep in botframework

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, botframework

I need write in CosmosDB from a waterfallStep in botframework, how can inject the dependency, the waterfallStep is a static delegate.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could inject the DbContext by constructor injection.

1. Register DbContext

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(option =>
           option.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
       //your rest code
   }
   ```
2. Inject `DbContext`

   ```
   public class MultiTurnPromptsBot : IBot
   {
       private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
       private const string WelcomeText = "Welcome to MultiTurnPromptBot. This bot will introduce multiple turns using prompts.  Type anything to get started.";

       private readonly MultiTurnPromptsBotAccessors _accessors;

       private DialogSet _dialogs;

       public MultiTurnPromptsBot(
           MultiTurnPromptsBotAccessors accessors
           , ApplicationDbContext context)
       {
           _accessors = accessors ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(accessors));
           _context = context;
           // The DialogSet needs a DialogState accessor, it will call it when it has a turn context.
           _dialogs = new DialogSet(accessors.ConversationDialogState);

           // This array defines how the Waterfall will execute.
           var waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
           {
               NameStepAsync,
               NameConfirmStepAsync,
           };

           // Add named dialogs to the DialogSet. These names are saved in the dialog state.
           _dialogs.Add(new WaterfallDialog("details", waterfallSteps));
           _dialogs.Add(new TextPrompt("name"));
       }        


       private async Task<DialogTurnResult> NameConfirmStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       {
           // Get the current profile object from user state.
           var userProfile = await _accessors.UserProfile.GetAsync(stepContext.Context, () => new UserProfile(), cancellationToken);

           // Update the profile.
           userProfile.Name = (string)stepContext.Result;
           _context.Add(new User { Name = userProfile.Name });
           _context.SaveChanges();
           // We can send messages to the user at any point in the WaterfallStep.
           await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Thanks {stepContext.Result}."), cancellationToken);

           // WaterfallStep always finishes with the end of the Waterfall or with another dialog; here it is a Prompt Dialog.
           return await stepContext.PromptAsync("confirm", new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Would you like to give your age?") }, cancellationToken);
       }        
   }
   ```